# Classes for Apostrophe Rich Text Widget

Tags: ckeditor, apostrophe-cms, html-sanitizing

I've run into an issue passing classes to the Apostrophe Rich Text Widget. I've updated the sanitizeHtml document, and I'm able to pass one custom class, but as soon as I try to add multiple classes in the widget stops working (at least the style selector does).

```
{{ apos.singleton(data.page, 'servicesSubtitle', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
          toolbar: [ 'Styles' ],
          styles: [
            {
              name: 'Services Subtitle',
              element: 'h3',
              attributes: {
                class: 'sub-title primary-color'
              }
            }
          ],
          class
          controls: {
            movable: false,
            removable: false
          }
        }) }}
```

This works if I only have:

```
attributes: {
    class: 'sub-title'
}
```

but doesn't when trying to pass two classes. I'm assuming there's something wonky with passing a space to that parameter, since it always grabs the first chunk of text, but I could be totally wrong about that. I figure I'm missing something really obvious, but cant figure it out or find any docs about it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known CKEditor bug that the Apostrophe team hasn't quite pinned down. Multiple classes WILL work in certain cases (change the order, try different phrases)

This is a crummy answer. We'd love a contribution!